# Expand a date range in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, nosql

I have a document structure like

```
{
  "startDate": ISODate("2015-01-01T00:00:00Z"),
  "endDate" : ISODate("2015-01-10T00:00:00Z"),
  "foo" : "bar"
}
```

Is it possible to expand the date range like this?

```
{
 "dates": [
           ISODate("2015-01-01T00:00:00Z"),
           ISODate("2015-01-02T00:00:00Z"),
           ISODate("2015-01-03T00:00:00Z"),
           ISODate("2015-01-04T00:00:00Z"),
           ISODate("2015-01-05T00:00:00Z"),
           ISODate("2015-01-06T00:00:00Z"),
           ISODate("2015-01-07T00:00:00Z"),
           ISODate("2015-01-08T00:00:00Z"),
           ISODate("2015-01-09T00:00:00Z"),
           ISODate("2015-01-10T00:00:00Z")
        ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You may need to elaborate on this a bit more but *yes it is possible to store that data as you've described it.* Here's an example, using your document model,  of such *an array of dates* in a document in a collection. Personally, I would look at modifying this as I've described at the end but of course it all depends on what your queries need to do with the data.

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("55474c322e8f6b5a9dda1a0f"),
"dates" : [ 
    ISODate("2015-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"), 
    ISODate("2015-01-02T00:00:00.000Z"), 
    ISODate("2015-01-03T00:00:00.000Z"), 
    ISODate("2015-01-04T00:00:00.000Z"), 
    ISODate("2015-01-05T00:00:00.000Z"), 
    ISODate("2015-01-06T00:00:00.000Z"), 
    ISODate("2015-01-07T00:00:00.000Z"), 
    ISODate("2015-01-08T00:00:00.000Z"), 
    ISODate("2015-01-09T00:00:00.000Z"), 
    ISODate("2015-01-10T00:00:00.000Z")
]
}
```

*Are you perhaps asking "how" to actually do so or how to work with them?* Pending what your use case is, you may want to alter that document model and opt for a different approach than a pure array of dates. I may instead use an array of subdocuments as shown in this example and I've included an example of a query that retrieves an element as well. Multiple people could, **and likely will herein,** suggest doing this in different ways, without more clarity regarding the use case.

```
//Example using subdocs
{
"_id" : ObjectId("55474e332e8f6b5a9dda1a10"),
"dates" : [ 
    {
        "date" : ISODate("2015-01-01T00:00:00.000Z")
    }, 
    {
        "date" : ISODate("2015-01-02T00:00:00.000Z")
    },  
... etc

  //using embedded docs
  db.rangeTest.find(
 {'dates.date': {$gte:ISODate("2015-01-08T00:00:00.000Z"), $lte:ISODate("2015-01-09T00:00:00.000Z")}},
{_id:0, 'dates.$':1} )
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to expand the date range like this?

Yes, using a query like this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
{ 
  $addFields: { 
    diff1: { 
      $divide: [ 
        { $subtract: [ "$endDate", "$startDate" ] }, 1000*60*60*24 
      ]
    }
  }
},
{ 
  $addFields: { 
    dates: {
      $map: {
        input: { $range: [ 0, { $add: [ "$diff1", 1 ] } ] },
        in: {
            $add: [ "$startDate", { $multiply: [ "$$this", 1000*60*60*24 ] } ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
]);
```